# Apply Effect to one or group of buses in a render callback

Tags: ios, core-audio

I have a render callback with 20 buses routed to a mixer and need to apply an effect to only some of these buses.

Do I need different callbacks for this or I can get it with the same render ?

Comment: Did you set 20 inputs of a mixer to a render callback?

Comment: 20 for this project, I have other projects with more than 40

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect the presence of the mixer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

You can manually add effects in-between your mixer and your callbacks.  So instead of setting the callback on the mixer input directly, you would create an effect unit for each bus that needs it, connect the effect to the mixer input, then set the input callback on the effect. (Most straightforward)

Example:

```
AUGraphConnectNodeInput(inGraph, sourceEffect, inSourceOutputNumber, mixerNode, inDestInputNumber);
AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback (inGraph, sourceEffect,0,&inputCallbackStruct);
```

You can keep a reference to each effect, then within your callback manually call AudioUnitRender on the effect. (Kind of complicated)

If you wish to use a single effect for this processing across multiple busses, you could use two mixers.  All the busses that need effect would be routed to the "Effect Mixer", then the effect can be on the output of the "Effect Mixer", and the output of the effect can go to your main mixer.  (Most efficient)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, Dave.

Comment: Dave. I've been testing it. Setting a bus for another mixer or effect, seems to throw and independent render. For example, if I set bus 1 directly to a delay Node ( and delay Node to input 1 of mixer) the callback throws a bus 0 for this effect bus, then another render for the main mixer with no effect buses (bus 0, 2, 3, 4, .... ) Is it a normal behavior ? .... If so, it is a pain in the ass cause it desynchronizes my channels.. I'll have to make many code modifications

Comment: Are you using an AUGraph? How are you connecting the effects?

Comment: int inBusTest=6; if (busNumber==inBusTest) {
            result = AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback (processingGraph,delay1Node,0, &inputCallbackStruct);
        } else {
            result = AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback (processingGraph, mixerNode,busNumber,&inputCallbackStruct);
        }

Comment: AUGraphConnectNodeInput (processingGraph,delay1Node,0,mixerNode,inBusTest);

Comment: OK.  You should be using [AUGraphConnectNodeInput](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/1502636-augraphconnectnodeinput?language=objc) for a direct connection, and AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback to set a render callback.

Comment: Do you mean... I should use AUGraphConnectNodeInput instead of AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback for the "effects" buses ?

Comment: Cool Dave. I was doing the same in reverse order, but it works exactly the same. I suppose is a normal behaviors. Putting bus 6 to effect, render inBusNumber runs in this order : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 0, 7, 8 .... I guess it's the normal behaviour ..

Comment: Thanks Dave, you made my week! I Really appreciate your help! God bless you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136380/discussion-between-fischer-and-dave).